# How to install MSBuild on old MSBuild installation folder on Windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, msbuild

I am writing a powershell script to automatically build .NET projects on TeamCity. The first step is installing msbuild. Below is the script I get so far:

```bsh
# download msbuild
$Url = 'https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe'
$msBuildInstaller = ([System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%TEMP%\vs_BuildTools.exe"))
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile "$msBuildInstaller" $Url

# install msbuild
$installDir = "$Env:UserProfile\msbuild"
$installDirCache = "$Env:UserProfile\msbuild\cache"
$installDirShared = "$Env:UserProfile\msbuild\shared"
Start-Process -FilePath "$msBuildInstaller" -Verb RunAs -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.SDK --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.TargetingPack --norestart --quiet --force --path install=$installDir --path cache=$installDirCache --path shared=$installDirShared"
```

With this script, I can install msbuild at `$installDir`. But when I delete the `$installDir` in window explorer and run the script again, it doesn't work.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Please let me know if you have special reason to manually delete the folders to test, this is delete, not uninstall :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `VS2017` and `VS2019`, it actually calls `VS installer(vs-installer.exe)` to install the specified components and workloads, so does `Build Tools for VS2017`(vs_buildtools.exe).

When you install the build tools by `vs_buildtools.exe`, it will call `vs-installer.exe` to install those packages for you, and during this process it will not only download the packages and files, it will also **register some registry keys and store info about your build tools package in related xx.config file**.

> But when I delete the $installDir in window explorer and run the
>   script again, it doesn't work.

So the **delete** operation you did actually deleted **part** of the build tools(not completely), when you run the script the second time, the installer will find that the version of VS build tools you want to install have been installed before by reading info from registry or xx.config file.

In this situation, VS installer won't work to install the build tools, that's why your script didn't work.

> How can I make it work?

Your original purpose is `automatically build .NET projects`, so you only need to determine whether build tools package is installed, if not, install it.(You can combine [Test-path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6) and [IF statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-6) to make this logic.)

You don't need to delete manually the build tools package to do the test. If you want to uninstall it, just choose the [uninstall switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). Manually deleting the files is not recommended way and in most situations, this is not needed. So the script's not working is expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I use uninstall switch and everything is fine.